# Decode weird JSON to a normal struct?

Tags: json, swift

To decode JSON, I had to create this struct:

```
struct Product: Decodable {
        var title: String
        var thumbnail: URL
        var price: Price
        var asin: String
    }
    
struct Price: Decodable {
        var current_price: Double
    }
```

The decoder looks like this:

```
let product = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Product.self, from: data)
```

As you can see, JSON `Price` has nested property `current_price`, which is not very useful for me.

I have a few questions:

1. How can I get rid of `Price` and store it directly as double to `Product`?
2. Prop: `thumbnail` is a `URL`. I want to store it as a `String`. Is this possible?

Comment: Thumbnail is a `String` not a `URL`. Can you share JSON too?

Comment: @Rob "thumbnail": "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09H73LTM6".  It's from JSON

Comment: That's a `String` already and not a `URL`.

Comment: @Sulthan (other) Rob's point is that it's already a String. Just type it as String and it'll decode that way.  PinkySweater97, also to (other) Rob's original point, if you'll post an example of JSON you're decoding, it'll make this go much faster. Otherwise we have to reverse engineer the JSON first to debug the solution (or hunt around for one of the several "almost, but not exactly this question" versions of this question; it's asked a lot and the answer is simple if slightly tedious, but it's hard to find a canonical version to link.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
struct Product: Decodable {
    var title: String
    var thumbnail: String
    var price: [String: Double]
    var asin: String
    
    var currentPrice: Double? { price["current_price"] }
}
```